# MongoDB Array Query Performance

Tags: arrays, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out what the best schema is for a dating site like app. User's have a listing (possibly many) and they can view other user listings to 'like' and 'dislike' them.

Currently i'm just storing the other persons listing id in a `likedBy` and `dislikedBy` array. When a user 'likes' a listing, it puts their listing id into the 'liked' listings arrays. However I would now like to track the timestamp that a user likes a listing. This would be used for a user's 'history list' or for data analysis.

I would need to do two separate queries:

`find all active listings that this user has not liked or disliked before`

and for a user's history of 'liked'/'disliked' choices

`find all the listings user X has liked in chronological order`

My current schema is:

```
listings
  _id: 'sdf3f'
  likedBy: ['12ac', 'as3vd', 'sadf3']
  dislikedBy: ['asdf', 'sdsdf', 'asdfas']
  active: bool
```

Could I do something like this?

```
listings
  _id: 'sdf3f'
  likedBy: [{'12ac', date: Date}, {'ds3d', date: Date}]
  dislikedBy: [{'s12ac', date: Date}, {'6fs3d', date: Date}]
  active: bool
```

I was also thinking of making a new collection for `choices`.

```
choices
  Id
  userId          // id of current user making the choice
  userlistId      // listing of the user making the choice
  listingChoseId  // the listing they chose yes/no
  type
  date
```

I'm not sure of the performance implications of having these choices in another collection when doing the `find all active listings that this user has not liked or disliked before`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It does make it hard for anyone to comment on what sort of schema to use when you do not actually say how you are intending the use it. Presumably you have a reason for needing to add timestamp information, so if you shared you want to use that in your question, then there is something to answer.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn , I re-wrote it a bit to make it easier to understand. Basically I need to be able to run a query to find all no chosen listings and a separate query to get the user's history of 'likes' and 'dislikes'.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well you obviously thought it was a good idea to have these embedded in the "listings" documents so your additional usage patterns to the cases presented here worked properly. With that in mind there is no reason to throw that away.

To clarify though, the structure you seem to want is something like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "sdf3f",
    "likedBy": [
         { "userId": "12ac",  "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z") },
         { "userId": "as3vd", "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z") },
         { "userId": "sadf3", "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z") }
    ],
    "dislikedBy": [
        { "userId": "asdf",   "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z") },
        { "userId": "sdsdf",  "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z") },
        { "userId": "asdfas", "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z") }
    ],
    "active": true
}
```

Which is all well and fine except that there is one catch. Because you have this content in two array fields you would not be able to create an index over both of those fields. That is a restriction where only one array type of field (or multikey) can be be included within a compound index.

So to solve the obvious problem with your first query not being able to use an index, you would structure like this instead:

```js
{
    "_id": "sdf3f",
    "votes": [
        { 
            "userId": "12ac",
            "type": "like", 
            "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z")
        },
        {
            "userId": "as3vd",
            "type": "like",
            "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z")
        },
        { 
            "userId": "sadf3", 
            "type": "like", 
            "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z")
        },
        { 
            "userId": "asdf", 
            "type": "dislike",
            "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z")
        },
        {
            "userId": "sdsdf",
            "type": "dislike", 
            "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z")
        },
        { 
            "userId": "asdfas", 
            "type": "dislike",
            "date": ISODate("2014-04-09T07:30:47.091Z")
        }
    ],
    "active": true
}
```

This allows an index that covers this form:

```js
db.post.ensureIndex({
    "active": 1,
    "votes.userId": 1, 
    "votes.date": 1, 
    "votes.type": 1 
})
```

Actually you will probably want a few indexes to suit your usage patterns, but the point is now can have indexes you can use.

Covering the first case you have this form of query:

```js
db.post.find({ "active": true, "votes.userId": { "$ne": "12ac" } })
```

That makes sense considering that you clearly are not going to have both an like and dislike option for each user. By the order of that index, at least active can be used to filter because your negating condition needs to scan everything else. No way around that with any structure.

For the other case you probably want the userId to be in an index before the date and as the first element. Then your query is quite simple:

```js
db.post.find({ "votes.userId": "12ac" })
    .sort({ "votes.userId": 1, "votes.date": 1 })
```

But you may be wondering that you suddenly lost something  in that getting the count of "likes" and "dislikes" was as easy as testing the size of the array before, but now it's a little different. Not a problem that cannot be solved using aggregate:

```js
db.post.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$votes" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "active": "$active"
       },
       "likes": { "$sum": { "$cond": [
           { "$eq": [ "$votes.type", "like" ] },
           1,
           0
       ]}},
       "dislikes": { "$sum": { "$cond": [
           { "$eq": [ "$votes.type", "dislike" ] },
           1,
           0
       ]}}
])
```

So whatever your actual usage form you can store any important parts of the document to keep in the grouping `_id` and then evaluate the count of "likes" and "dislikes" in an easy manner.

You may also not that changing an entry from like to dislike can also be done in a single atomic update.

There is much more you can do, but I would prefer this structure for the reasons as given.

Comment: Why hasn't this received a ton more upvotes? super clear answer